# Finding root node for every element recursively in SQL

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following sample from the table **category**:

```
category_id |                         category_name                          | super_category
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------
           1 | Features                                                      +|
             |                                                                |
           2 | Alle SACDs                                                    +|              1
             |                                                                |
           3 | Formate                                                       +|
             |                                                                |
           4 | Box-Sets                                                      +|              3
             |                                                                |
           5 | Action, Thriller & Horror                                     +|              4
             |                                                                |
           6 | Alternative                                                   +|              4
             |                                                                |
           7 | Blues                                                         +|              4
             |                                                                |
           8 | Country                                                       +|              4
             |                                                                |
           9 | Alternative Country & Americana& Country                       |              8
          10 | Bestseller& Country                                            |              8
          11 | Bluegrass& Country                                             |              8
...
```

The column **super_category** lists the immediate parent category for any given category. When super_category is NULL, that category is a **main** category.

Table with all of the **main** categories:

`SELECT * FROM category WHERE super_category IS NULL;`

```
 category_id | category_name  | super_category
-------------+----------------+----------------
           1 | Features      +|
             |                |
           3 | Formate       +|
             |                |
         497 | Formats       +|
             |                |
         544 | Genres        +|
             |                |
         923 | Interpreten   +|
             |                |
         941 | Kategorien    +|
             |                |
       19208 | Schauspieler  +|
             |                |
       19211 | Shop-überblick+|
             |                |
       19502 | Shops         +|
             |                |
       21350 | Subjects      +|
             |                |
       21513 | Unter 10 EUR  +|
             |                |
       21520 | Unter 15 EUR  +|
```

I need to write a recursive query that outputs a table that lists all the categories and which **main** categories the belong to.

So far I only have the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE query AS (
    SELECT cat.category_id, cat.super_category
    FROM category cat
    WHERE cat.super_category IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT query.category_id, cat.super_category
    FROM query JOIN category cat on cat.super_category = query.category_id
)
SELECT * FROM query;
```

The logic is as follows:

We define the base case where the category is a main category (super_category IS NULL)

Then we define the recursive case, but I am not sure how I should define it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are in the correct path with the use of a recursive CTE. You can do:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select category_id, category_name, super_category, 0 as level
  from category
 union all
  select n.category_id, n.category_name, c.super_category, n.level + 1
  from n
  join category c on c.category_id = n.super_category
)
select category_id, category_name, super_category
from n
where (category_id, level) in (
  select distinct on (category_id) category_id, level 
  from n
  order by category_id, level desc
)
```